# How was the black body intensity vs wavelength (or frequency) radiation curve historically produced?

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation, thermal-radiation, intensity

[image]

I have read that Wilhelm Wien gave his formula to match the radiation curve of a black body as shown in the picture; which works well in high frequency region. Another formula by Rayleigh-Jeans is fine with low frequency EM waves. Then the correct function to describe the curve was given by Max Planck.

I have been trying to find out how this curve was experimentally discovered in the first place. So far I have come to know two scientists named Lummer and Pringsheim experimentally determined the curve but I can’t seem to find their method on the internet.

If someone could shed some light on the matter, it would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: the experiment is discussed in this talk https://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/~mph/concepts/concepts_quanta1.pdf

Comment: the reference to the LandP work in an  old journal  is number 4 herehttps://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1901ApJ....14..335R

Comment: A Treatise On Heat by M.N. Saha and B.N. Srivastava, page 532, explains the methods of Lummer and Pringsheim.

Comment: @Vikash I couldn’t find it in that exact page, though there was some mention in the pages around 630 but still I didn’t see the method of the experiment there.

Answer (score 1):

With correction: A Treatise On Heat by M.N. Saha and B.N. Srivastava, pages 302-304, explains the methods of Lummer and Pringsheim. See attached screenshot:
[image]

[image]